# How to increase height of subcategories Item on side menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, angular7

I work on angular 7 I work on app display categories reports and and reports sub

categories for every category selected .

I face Issue I need to increase Height of every sub category reports .

as example SwTest as Image I need to Increase height of cell of sub categories only .

On my stackblitz full sample work of menu 
[See the code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-tym4bg?file=app/app.component.css)

For subcategory :

```
  <div *ngIf="subrep.reportCategoryID === rep.reportCategoryID" class="wrapper" >


              <a href="/reportdetails?id={{subrep.reportID}}">


   <span class="sideNav nav navbar">{{subrep.reportName}}</span>
    </a>
  </div>

.wrapper{
  background:#f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #d1b792;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d1b792;

}
```

[image: Increase height of sub categories]

Comment: can any one help me

Comment: can any one help me I add property heigh :50px on wrapper and cell heigh increase but text not align to center on left

Answer (score 0):

You have a `wrapper` CSS class on the submenu `<div>`. Try this:

```css
.wrapper { 
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

It'll look like this:

[image]

Comment: yes it is done but remain small thing if possible help me how to remove gray vertical line that display left of subcategories